# Decide if the improper integral of a Fourier transform converges

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I have the function:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
e^{-x^{10}} & ,x>0\\ 
-e^{-x^{10}} & ,x<0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I need to answer:

- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f}(\omega)|d\omega < \infty$

and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Do you know plancherels theorem? Do you know the connection between smoothness of the Fourier transform and decay of the original function? Do you know the Fourier inversion theorem?

Comment: Yeah, I understand how it might help me decide that the Fourier transform is differentiated. But I can't see how it can help me with the second question.

Comment: If an integrable function has an integrable Fourier transform, Fourier inversion yields $f(x)=\int \hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i x \xi}\,d\xi $ for (almost all) $x$. In particular, $f$ has a continuous "version" (with respect to a.e. equality). Is this the case for your function?

Comment: Yes it is. So I know $\int \widehat{f}(\xi)e^{2i\pi\xi }d\xi $ converges. How can I tell that it is absolutely converges?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x \downarrow 0}f(x)$ and what is $\lim_{x \uparrow 0} f(x)$?

Comment: So if I get it right. Assume $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f}(\omega)|d\omega < \infty$. by the inversion theorem and by the fact that $f$ is absolutely integrable we get that we can take the transform of $\widehat{f}$ and to have a continuous version of $f$ which is impossible because $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $0$ and thus $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f}(\omega)|d\omega$ does not converge.

Comment: yes, exactly! ${}$

Answer (score 1):

> If an integrable function has an integrable Fourier transform, Fourier inversion yields $f(x)=\int \hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i x \xi}\,d\xi $ for (almost all) $x$. In particular, $f$ has a continuous "version" (with respect to a.e. equality).   -- [PhoemueX](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442043/decide-if-the-improper-integral-of-a-fourier-transform-converges#comment2938210_1442043)

... which is not the case for this $f$:

> Assume $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f}(\omega)|d\omega < \infty$. by the inversion theorem and by the fact that $f$ is absolutely integrable we get that we can take the transform of $\widehat{f}$ and to have a continuous version of $f$ which is impossible because $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $0$ and thus $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f}(\omega)|d\omega$ does not converge. -- [YaG32](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442043/decide-if-the-improper-integral-of-a-fourier-transform-converges#comment2940661_1442043)